# Oracle, Can't get details from the same column

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-attribute-value

I have a table named PARAMETER looking like this:

```
ID - number
NAME - varchar2
VALUE - varchar2
```

I have this query witch is 'extracting' the date from the string:

```
SELECT * from PARAMETER
where (NAME = 'From') and SUBSTR(VALUE, 1, 2)>='01' 
and SUBSTR(ALUE, -7, 5)>='11' and SUBSTR(VALUE, -4, 4) >='2012'
```

Now I need to run it again changing only: `where (NAME = 'From')`  to  `where (NAME = 'To')`

and compare the results. I can't find a way to do this. Is there a trick?

Comment: First of all it seems to me you are trying to compare Strings as if they were Dates or Numbers. The >= operator takes into account only  the length of the string not its numerical value.
For instance 001 > 99 is true even though it would be false if they were Numbers (Integers). 

I think the first trick is that one. 
ANd also I dont get what you wanna get from your SUBSTR operations.
Substr(string, starting point, length). What do you expect to get from SUBSTR(VALUE, -4, 4)
Last but not least: provide us with a sample value of the column VALUE.

Comment: This is what the VALUE column have inside: 29/11/2012

Comment: Alright and please explain what you wanna achieve with your query. In words I mean. For example: I want to Find All Entries that Start (i.e. Name= 'From') from 01/11/2012 and end at 20/11/2012 (i.e. Name ='To')

Comment: This is what exacly I need: I want to Find All Entries that Start (i.e. Name= 'From') from 01/11/2012 and end at 20/11/2012 (i.e. Name ='To')

Comment: The reason why so many people rail against the EAV model is prescisely because it throws up problems like this.

Comment: I agree, but I need to get the values somehow, The database is huge and it's a sueside to rewrite it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * From Parameter
Where Name='From'
AND TO_DATE(VALUE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= TO_DATE('01/11/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND TO_DATE(VALUE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= TO_DATE('20/11/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
UNION
Select * From Parameter
Where Name='To'
AND TO_DATE(VALUE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= TO_DATE('01/11/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND TO_DATE(VALUE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= TO_DATE('20/11/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

This will give you all dates that start from 01/11/2012 until 20/11/2012
AND all the dates that end in that period as well.
I dont know if thats what you ask for.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to query the table twice and compare the results of both subqueries, for example:

```
with v_from as (
  SELECT * from PARAMETER
  where (NAME = 'From') and SUBSTR(VALUE, 1, 2)>='01' 
  and SUBSTR(VALUE, -7, 5)>='11' and SUBSTR(VALUE, -4, 4) >='2012'),
v_to as (
  SELECT * from PARAMETER
  where (NAME = 'From') and SUBSTR(VALUE, 1, 2)>='01' 
  and SUBSTR(VALUE, -7, 5)>='11' and SUBSTR(VALUE, -4, 4) >='2012')
select f.id, f.name, f.value as from_value, t.value as to_value 
from v_from f
join v_to t on f.id = t.id
```

This assumes you always have both to and from values; if not, you'll have to use an outer join.